# jquery ajax using 'addresses' to update url for bookmarking

Tags: jquery, url, firefox

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    contM = $('#main-content');
    contS = $('#second-content');
    $(contM).hide();
    $(contS).hide();
    function loadURL(url) {
        console.log("loadURL: " + url);
        $.post(url,{post_loader: 1},{post_loader: 1}, function(data){
                                                               $(contM).html($(data));
                                                               $(contM).show();
                                                               });
    }


    // Event handlers
    $.address.init(function(event) {
        console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
    }).change(function(event) {
        $.post($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'), {post_loader: 1}, function(data){
                                                                                               $(contM).html($(data));
                                                                                               $(contM).show();
                                                                                               });
        console.log("change");
    })

    $('.update-main a').click(function(){
        loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

I'm using this code to make calls to a server to update the main content of a web page.  Everything works fine in Google Chrome, but fails to execute properly in Firefox.

The strange thing is that when I have the console open to monitor server communication, the application works fine, only when it is closed do problems occur : the script starts to communicate with the server, but before it receives the data the browser jumps to the source url.

I keep getting this error in the firebug console : e.success.call is not a function
webDev/lostine/wp-content/themes/lostine/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js
Line 121

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with the console.log() statements commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle different browsers with and without console, I use a slightly adapted version of Paul Irish's wrapper, http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog :

```
window.log = function () 
{
    if (window.console) {
        if (console.firebug) {
            console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        } else {
            console.log.call(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As [wesgarrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62140/wesgarrison) commented, `console` isn't always present in FireFox like it is in Chrome and you'll get an `console is undefined` error.  You need to comment out the `console.log()` lines when not debugging, or wrap them in a `if(console){}` check.

The reason it works when the console is out...`console` is defined then, no errors :)